# Animation that does not work fluidly

Tags: android, android-animation

i have issues with my code, when I try to run the first animation which consists of resizing the image to about 50% whilst making it a circle and then a shared preference to another activity which has a ripple reveal effect, it all kind of happens at the same time and the shared element mostly doesn't work.

My second issue is that when i use the onDestroy button, it jumps back and does not return the image back to its original size.

well here's my code any help will be greatly appreciated...

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView Lemon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Lemon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.square);
        Lemon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //holds refrence to circle Transform.
                //this is to make it a circle
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(R.drawable.birds)//the image
                    .transform(new CircleTransform())
                    .resize(128, 128)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(Lemon);//and what image view to put it in
                Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.reduce);
                Lemon.startAnimation(a);

                //resize 
                Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.reduce);
                Lemon.startAnimation(a);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Lemon.clearAnimation();
    }
}
```

sample.java

```
public class sample extends Activity{
    ImageView Big;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample_b);

        Big = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bigBird);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Big.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = Big.getViewTreeObserver();
            if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
                viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        circularRevealActivity();
                        Big.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
   }

   private void circularRevealActivity() {     
       int cx = Big.getWidth() / 2;
       int cy = Big.getHeight() / 2;

       float finalRadius = Math.max(Big.getWidth(), Big.getHeight());

       // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
       Animator circularReveal = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(Big, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
       circularReveal.setDuration(1000);

       // make the view visible and start the animation
       Big.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       circularReveal.start();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       Big.clearAnimation();
   }
}
```

activitymain.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.nazim.reducesharedelement.MainActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/birds"
            android:id="@+id/square"
            android:onClick="animation"
            android:fillAfter="true"
            android:fillEnabled="true"
            android:transitionName="@string/sharedelement"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

sample_b.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:src="@drawable/birds"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:transitionName="@string/sharedelement"
            android:id="@+id/bigBird"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

compiled

```
 dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    }
```

I appologise for the bad formatting but I struggle to work this. Please give explantion in simple terms please. any help given will be greatly appreciated.